# How quickly check whether to run npm install Node

Tags: node.js, npm

Next script goes thought all folders and installs dependencies

```
var fs            = require( "fs" ),
    path          = require( "path" ),
    child_process = require( "child_process" );

var rootPath = "./";

var dirs = fs.readdirSync( rootPath )
    .filter( function( dir ) {
        return fs.statSync( path.join( rootPath, dir )).isDirectory();
    });

var install = function()
{
    if ( dirs.length === 0 )
        return;

    var dir = dirs.shift();
    console.log( "installing dependencies for : '" + dir + "'" );

    child_process.exec( "npm prune --production | npm install", {
        cwd: rootPath + dir
    }, install );
};
install();
```

How to run npm install command only if package.json exists in folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
ls | grep package.json && (npm prune --production | npm install)
```

I assume you are running this in Linux.

In theory, if I remember correctly, the ouput of the command `ls` will be piped to the `grep` command, and only if the `grep` command will have found a result, then the commands `(npm prune --production | npm install)` will be executed.

This is not tested by me at the moment of writting this, since I don't have a Linux box right now to test this, but I hope it works.

**UPDATE:**
The efficient command, as per Dan's comment would be

```
test -f package.json && (npm prune --production | npm install)
```

Comment: `ls | grep package.json` is a horrible way of doing `test -f package.json`

Comment: @DanD advice please how to get meaningful log also?

Comment: I'm learning new things about Linux every day, thank you Dan.

Comment: @francesca What do you mean by meaningful log? Maybe something like ``test -f package.json && echo "package.json exists. Executing npm install..." && (npm prune --production | npm install)``

Comment: @CristianSmocot log that shows folders where npm install was executed and packages that were installed